# Bootstrap button push causes scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap Card that I am using to display the red lamp. When a user pushes the start button the red lamp changes green and the start button disappears. A short amount of time elapses and the green light changes back to read and a "brakes" button appears that the user needs to push in the shortest amount of time.

Unfortunately, when the user pushes start on a mobile device, the browser "scrolls" slightly (as pictured). I am using jQuery to add and remove classes to make the light change color and the buttons to disappear and reappear. But not sure what I have added that causes the scrolling on mobile device. Desktops are not affected.

[image: Mobile screen moves on button push]

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, and for the time being the fix is simple. It's the extra line of text that caused the scrolling. So I shortened the text and this solves the issue. But in future, I guess there's something with padding going on? Not sure. But this is solved for now.

[image: Extra line of text]